# How to deal with "non-const reference cannot bind to bit-field" error?

Tags: c++, c++17

I encounter this error while using emplace_back to construct a bit field structure in a vector:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo(uint32_t foo1): foo1(foo1) {}
  uint32_t foo1 : 4;
};


int main()
{
  vector<Foo> fooVector;
  Foo foo = Foo(10);

  fooVector.emplace_back(foo.foo1); // Error: non-const reference cannot bind to bit-field
}
```

I have found that I can avoid this error by either using push_back (but I prefer emplace_back for performance reasons), or by modifying the concerned line like so:

```
fooVector.emplace_back(uint32_t(foo.foo1)); // Don't raise error
```

Is it the proper way to deal with it?
Why does this solution work?

Comment: `uint32_t foo1 : 8;` -> `uint8_t foo1;`

Comment: Get an interesting and helpful warning from gcc once I crank up the warning level: *warning: conversion from 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} to 'unsigned char:4' may change value* Usually when you have a conversion take place, even one you didn't expect, there will be a temporary involved and references to temporaries require the extra `const` guarantee. Changing a temporary's usually pointless, so C++ doesn't allow it to prevent avoidable bugs.

Comment: `uint32_t(foo.foo1)` is a function-style C cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

```
template< class... Args >
reference emplace_back( Args&&... args );
```

`Args&&` in this case gets deduced to `uint32_t&`, and, as the error says, a bit-field (`Foo::foo1`) cannot be bound to this type since it is a non-const reference.

In general, you cannot have a reference or a pointer to a bit-field because it has no address. A const reference works because it creates a temporary that is copy initialized with the value of the bit-field, and binds to that temporary instead.

You can indeed do an intermediate cast, like in your example or more explicitly like this:

```
fooVector.emplace_back(static_cast<uint32_t>(foo.foo1));
```

However, I am questioning why you want a 8-bit bitfield of a `uint32_t` instead of just using a `uint8_t`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. About the bitfield instead of the uint8_t, it's just for the example :)